# Mysql update trigger only on specific id

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have tables that looks like this

*commons_db.sites*

```
user_id | active 
1       |    0   
2       |    1
```

*commons_db.users*

```
site_id  | user_id | status
50       |    1    |   1
51       |    2    |   0
```

I wanted to create a trigger such that the `status` column of a `site_id` changes when  I update its `active` column. So far it looks like this.

```
UPDATE commons_db.users
SET `status` = ! NEW.active
WHERE user_id in (
    SELECT user_id FROM
        commons_db.sites
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT * FROM commons_db.users) AS users 
        using (user_id)
    );
```

It works but it also changes the `status` of other ids. I tried to add a line

```
AND OLD.active != NEW.active
```

but it doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes I want status and active be inverse of each other. I don't make any changes in the user_id. I only used it to join two tables I need in the trigger

Comment: it gives an error: ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'NEW'

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tables in your example, this works fine for me:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER tr_sites_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON sites
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NOT NEW.active <=> OLD.active THEN
      UPDATE users SET status = NOT NEW.active WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;
  END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4eym68zt)

Comment: Will produce incorrect result when either intial or final `active` is NULL

Comment: Quite possibly correct. I, possibly incorrectly, assumed that the two columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Use ```IF NOT NEW.active <=> OLD.active THEN``` simply.

Comment: @Akina Thank you! I was not even aware of that null safe equality operator.